# Netsuite Handle Changed Items

Tags: netsuite

I wrote SuiteScript  attch it to event "submit after', Apply it to Customer and it works fine, when i create or edit customer. Now I want attach this script to Item, another words when new Item create or edit. What I need to choose from "Applies To" for that? (http://joxi.ru/uHTeUhjKTJCYBexbX8Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**
you have to select all the different item types individually (e.g. Serialized Inventory Item, Sales Tax Item etc)

**Long Answer**
Transaction and Items are not actual record types in Netsuite. Items is just an abstraction for the combination of different item types which is not available at every customization level. For a complete list of item types see

https://system.netsuite.com/app/common/item/item.nl
https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/common/item/item.nl